# Как поместить картинку в TextView используя setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-xml

Хотелось бы поподробнее узнать о такой вещи как `CompoundDrawable`, а точнее о строке

```
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Что дают последние четыре параметра `(left, top, right, bottom)`?

Comment: Есть же [офф. доки](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)).

Answer (score 3):

Код

```
 textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,0,0)
```

позволяет установить иконки в `textView`. `left, top, right, bottom` расположение иконки относительно текста

в xml пишется так

```
<TextView
    ...
     android: drawableTop = "@drawable/ic_launcher"
... />
```

Comment: т, е можно размещать и imageview в тексте? А что дает параметр button?

Comment: нет. вы можете размещать только ресурсы(R.drawable.ic_lounch), но не ImageView =)

Comment: ок, у меня в папке mipmap есть картинка и я хочу разместить ее  под текстом в Relativelayout, Если параметры  left, top, right позволяют указывать расположение картинки на экране, то что делает параметр bottom и что записывать в место него четрвертым?

Comment: bottom  - под текстом. если вы хотите установить только bottom, то укажите только боттом, в остальное нули textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,0,R.drawable.ic_launch), Если картинка большая, лучше использовать отдельно ImageView,

Comment: Вот существующий код, но выдает ошибку в последней строке:                                                                                                          TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        text.setText("просто текст") TextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(10, 10, 25, 30);

Comment: (10, 10, 25, 30) - Вы должны указывать id ресурсов, а не магические цифры